# Compute the average intercept and slope for a group from the lmer or lme function?

Tags: r, lme4

I was wondering, does anyone know how print the output `lmer` or `lme` summary data for a group within a data set in R? For example if this is what the header of my data (`df`) looks like:

| SubjectID | week | group | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 12.5 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 10.6 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 6.4 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 6.3 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 23.5 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 | 15.2 |

And I want to get the specific intercept and slope for the subjects in group 3 only. I would use the `lmer` function in the code below:

```
fit.coef <- lmer(weight ~ week*group + (week|SubjectID),
                data = df, 
                control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

I can get statistics for an individual in the data set or the intercept and slopes across the entire data set but I can't figure out how to calculate these specific values for all the items within a group (e.g. all subjects within group 3). I know this is easy in SAS but I can't figure out any way to do this in R despite googling for hours.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us a reproducible example but I think you're looking for `coef()` ?

It gives the predicted effects for each random effect term, for each level of the grouping variable, in the example below the intercept and slope for each subject.

```r
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
coef(m1)
$Subject
    (Intercept)       Days
308    253.6637 19.6662617
309    211.0064  1.8476053
310    212.4447  5.0184295
330    275.0957  5.6529356
331    273.6654  7.3973743
332    260.4447 10.1951090
333    268.2456 10.2436499
334    244.1725 11.5418676
335    251.0714 -0.2848792
337    286.2956 19.0955511
349    226.1949 11.6407181
350    238.3351 17.0815038
351    255.9830  7.4520239
352    272.2688 14.0032871
369    254.6806 11.3395008
370    225.7921 15.2897709
371    252.2122  9.4791297
372    263.7197 11.7513080
```

Comment: I was hoping to get the mean intercept and slope values for each group individually (for example, the values across all subjects in group 3). Do you know how to do this?

Comment: That's what I believe I've shown right here ...